# Eclipse Lombok annotations not compiled why ? Any solution ?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

I'm still stuck in my issue : [Eclipse Lombok annotations not compiled... Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301333/eclipse-lombok-annotations-not-compiled-why) 
If any one of you have any solution or way to the solution I'll be glad to try it.

See you !

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate question, it's the duplication of one of my question that still haven't any response.

Comment: There are [ways](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) to draw attention to an unanswered question. Reposting isn't one of them.